# Recursive function in C#

Tags: c#, list, recursion

I have a object, let's call it "Friend".
This object has method "GetFriendsOfFriend", that returns a `List<Friend>`.

Given a user input of say 5, all of the Friends friends and the friends friends friends (you get the point) down in a level of 5 (this can be up to 20).

This may be a lot of calculations, so I don't know if recursion is the best solution.

Does anyone have a smart idea of 
1. How to do this recursive function best?
2. How to do it without recursion.

Thanks!

Comment: How are friends actually related to one another?

Comment: Without details of these calculations and the data involved this is impossible to answer except to say both iterative and recursive solutions are almost certainly possible. But anything more specific or definitive will require the details.

Comment: Also consider what should happen in the case of mutual friends. You don't want to end up with an infinite recurse.

Comment: @CodyGray: He already has mentioned a limit to recursion. The problem with mutual friends is likely to be the duplication you may get.

Comment: I am a friend of Annish. Annish is a friend of me. Good luck!  You'll need some way of detecting and dealing with cycles in your data.

Comment: He could solve that with a flood-fill algorithm

Comment: He could ignore double counting if he represented this as a 2-D matrix.  Use 0 for not a friend, and increment by one for each friend included (or not at all if it is already 1.)  If it is a non-zero value, it would indicate friendship.

Comment: @BlackVegetable, Tharen: Sure there are plenty of ways. I am just pointing out an obvious problem with a naive recursive search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whilst is is certainly possible to do this without recursion, I don't see a particular problem with what you're trying to do.  To prevent things going crazy, it might make sense to set a maximum to prevent your program from dying.

```
public class Friend
{
    public static readonly int MaxDepth = 8; // prevent more than 8 recursions

    private List<Friend> myFriends_ = new List<Friend>();

    // private implementation
    private void InternalFriends(int depth, int currDepth, List<Friend> list)
    {
        // Add "us"
        if(currDepth > 1 && !list.Contains(this))
            list.Add(this);

        if(currDepth <= depth)
        {
            foreach(Friend f in myFriends_)
            {
                if(!list.Contains(f))
                    f.InternalFriends(depth, depth + 1, list); // we can all private functions here.
            }
        }
    } // eo InternalFriends


    public List<Friend> GetFriendsOfFriend(int depth)
    {
        List<Friend> ret = new List<Friend>();
        InternalFriends(depth < MaxDepth ? depth : MaxDepth, 1, ret);
        return ret;
    }  // eo getFriendsOfFriend
} // eo class Friend
```

EDIT: Fixed an error in the code in that an actual friend would not get added, just "their" friends.  This is only necessary when adding friends after a depth of "1" (the first call).  I also made use of `Contains` to check for duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non recursive version of this code:

```
public static void ProcessFriendsOf(string person) {
    var toVisit = new Queue<string>();
    var seen = new HashSet<string>();

    toVisit.Enqueue(person);
    seen.Add(person);           

    while(toVisit.Count > 0) {
        var current = toVisit.Dequeue();    

        //process this friend in some way

        foreach(var friend in GetFriendsOfFriend(current)) {
            if (!seen.Contains(friend)) {
                toVisit.Enqueue(friend);
                seen.Add(friend);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It avoids infinite loop by keeping a HashSet of all members already seen and not adding a member to be processed more than once.

It visits friends using a Queue, in a way that is known as [Breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). If we use a Stack instead of a Queue, it becomes a [Depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), and would behave pretty much the same as a recursive approach (which uses an implicit stack - the call stack).